# How to left-align text in a SWT ToolItem?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I am upgrading an RCP application to use Eclipse 4.2.1. One of the problems I am having is that the alignment of text in toolbars has changed.

I can reproduce the issue with the following snippet, adapted from a standard [SWT snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet36.java). It simply creates a vertical ToolBar with 3 ToolItems. Each item has an image and some text.

When I run this snippet in Eclipse 3.7.2, the text of each ToolItem is left-aligned. In Eclipse 4.2.1, it is centre-aligned. I would like the text to remain left-aligned. Setting the style to SWT.LEFT does not help. Any suggestions?

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolItem;

public class Snippet36 {

  public static void main (final String [] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Image image = new Image (display, 16, 16);
    Color color = display.getSystemColor (SWT.COLOR_RED);
    GC gc = new GC (image);
    gc.setBackground (color);
    gc.fillRectangle (image.getBounds ());
    gc.dispose ();
    Shell shell = new Shell (display);
    ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar (shell, SWT.FLAT | SWT.BORDER | SWT.VERTICAL | SWT.RIGHT);
    Rectangle clientArea = shell.getClientArea ();
    toolBar.setLocation (clientArea.x, clientArea.y);
    String[] labels = new String[] {"Short", "Quite a bit longer", "OK"};
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
      ToolItem item = new ToolItem (toolBar, SWT.PUSH);
      item.setText(labels[i]);
      item.setImage (image);
    }
    toolBar.pack ();
    shell.open ();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) {
        display.sleep ();
      }
    }
    image.dispose ();
    display.dispose ();
  }
}
```

Comment: This issue is Linux only and has been raised as https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=397880

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it with Eclipse 4.2.1 and this it what I get:

[image]

Everything works fine.

Which version of SWT are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using SWT version 4.2.1. I now believe that this is platform specific - I am developing on Linux, but have confirmed that this does not occur on Windows.

Comment: @EmilyM I will check at home on linux and report back.

Comment: @EmilyM Ok, I can confirm, that it is platform dependent. Works on Windows, doesn't work on Linux with SWT 4.2.1. Have no solution for you, though. Maybe [file a bug](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/bugs.php)