# Toolbar item with text below the image in RCP application

Tags: text, eclipse-rcp, toolbar

I am implementing RCP Project with Toolbar as extension point.
I want both Image and text in Toolbar with text below the image
How can I do this through Toolbar Extension point ?

Comment: Do you mean you are adding a button on the toolbar and you want the image and text to show up?

Comment: yes,But My Requirement is that show text below the image in Toolbar button

Comment: Have you tried `IToolBarManager toolBar = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT | SWT.BOTTOM);`

Comment: Here are some references http://stackoverflow.com/q/13514603/462285 http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t31081.html

Comment: I think through the extension point you can only force the text but the alignment will probably be have to done via code.